# position iframe on specific content inside amazon

Tags: html, css, iframe

kinda new here
so I've been trying for the past 2hr to position an iframe and just couldnt get it right (or anywhere near that...)
my goal is to position an iframe of amazon just where "Hello, [name]" is written.
first I couldnt set an iframe because of their Same origin policy but I guess some pages aren't protected, like this one: [http://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B0051QVF7A/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_top?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0051QVF7A)

positioning the iframe on my account information just seem impossible (tried margin-left, right, divs and everything)

my goal would be somewhat like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQwyn.png

Comment: You should post the code that you attempted.

Comment: so you want some sort of auto login...is that correct

Comment: You want the iframe to be the size and exact location of the button where it says "Hello, [name]? This seems a little suspicious.

Comment: @chdltest lol its for cyber security class, I was also provided with example on yahoo.com, problem is example does not work on amazon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm a little skeptical about what this is for, I'll provide an answer for it anyways.

So you can't exactly target the location of where your iframe's initial screen will show up at (as it will always default to the top left corner if I'm not mistaken) but you can move the iframe itself around.

Knowing that, it's possible to create an iframe effect over the iframe itself.

You'll have an iframe that will be large enough to capture the button at first glance (which 1260px wide and 300px high is good enough)

You will then move the iframe to position the button to where you would like it to show up in using an absolute position and the top and left style.

Then create a new div to contain that iframe and give it a width and height to what the button's size would be and then remove the ability to scroll with `overflow: hidden;` and remove the scrolling by stating it within the iframe tag `scrolling="no"`.

You should then have the same results as below:

```css
#my-div { 
width: 128px;
height: 55px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
 
#my-iframe { 
position: absolute;
top: -42px;
left: -884px;
width: 1260px;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
<iframe src="http://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B0051QVF7A/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_top?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending" id="my-iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, thanks man! also I wasnt lying, I dont mind showing you im a bsc student in Israel (if you want proof PM me, if thats possible in this site)

Comment: It's alright, you don't really need to prove anything especially when I gave you the answer already lol won't really change much ;p